# sum digits from a very long number

Tags: c#, math

Assume I let  user input  number : 1298743257884834...(long as user need)

Let program tell how many digit are they ?

then give result by  SUM them = ?

Comment: This smells of homework...

Comment: It tastes like it aswell

Comment: I'd just ask for a string and iterate over it. No need to convert to a number.

Answer (score 2):

By using LINQ

```
string input = // get input from console, textbox, ...
int inputLength = input.Length; // get number of digits, although you don't need it here
int sum = input.Sum(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())); // summarize
```

Comment: Why `ToCharArray()`? `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: What do you propose instead?

Comment: Just `input.Sum(...)`. You can use LINQ on any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Since `string` already does so, there is no need to convert to array before using LINQ.

Comment: I was not aware of `string` implementing `IEnumerable<char>`, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the [`BigInteger` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) found in `System.Numerics`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can know the number of digits in this way:

```
string digits = TextBox1.Text;
long digitsnumber = digits.Length;
```

Then to sum each number, you need to loop in your string like an array of char, in this way, and cast the car value to an integer with the `GetNumericValue` method of `System.Char`:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (var c in digits)
{
   if (Char.IsNumber(c))
   {
       sum += (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
   }
}
```

Sum will be your result.

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray()` either. `foreach` supports `string`. YOu can use `foreach(var c in digits)` directly.

Comment: You're lacking error checking. Any non-numeric character silently decrements the sum by one.

Comment: I agree, I edited my code to improve it.